# User tagging for a specific function from their own library

Tags: discussion, tags, suggested-edits

I noticed in the Suggested Edit review queue that there was a series of seeming edits where questions were being tagged with [slider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/slider) and [rangeslider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rangeslider). The former seems a useful distinction but I found the latter odd since it's just a slightly more specific subset of sliders. However on investigation it seems that this [user ionDen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2832267/ionden?tab=activity) has been making lots of these edits to question that use their ionden framework, specifically with the rangeslider that's in the framework.

I don't know what their intent is, organisation for their edits maybe? Perhaps it's a mild attempt at self promotion, but either way it seems more to serve them than the community at large. Should this be treated any different to other mass tag edits when users feel the need to populate unnecessary seeming tags? Does it matter that they have a personal albeit small vested interest?

Comment: A quick glance of the questions tagged with it does seem to indicate a majority actually asks about that specific product.

Comment: @Gimby They're not improperly tagged, no. But it seems kind of redundant to have the tag especially if a lot of the activity comes from this particular user. Am I wrong about the consensus being to avoid function specific tags?

Comment: "_Should this be treated any different to other mass tag edits_" not really.  If it's really spammy then an appropriate flag.  Otherwise I think the usual guidelines are sufficient.

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan tags are for grouping questions, so no. but in my opinion the name of the tag is completely wrong, it should have been related to the product name and not to a feature of the product. Then the combi of tags would read "slider ionden" which is nice and narrow.